Woman relaxing in a bathtub slowly getting caught by an alien form
I remember trembling and having bad dreams after watching this movie in the 90's. 
The aliens look like a small vegetable with tentacles and they hijack people, I can't recall the title and I saw a movie that I thought the scene was in but I didn't see the scene (I could have missed it). I would say the movie is old, at least 70-80's. 
The woman is having a hot bath relaxing with something covering her eyes, and we see the creature going slowly for its target from the ceiling. 
The title of the movie and a picture/video of the scene would be so much appreciated, I feel like watching this movie again and have my share of bad dreams again. I'm fairly sure this is a classic, so it shouldn't be that hard to find, I'm sure a movie guru will have the anwser, have a nice day everyone.

Sounds like a scene from Abel Ferrara's Body Snatchers from 1993 with Gabrielle Anwar as the intended victim, but she doesn't have anything on her eyes.

This is possible, I was around 7-8 years old when I watched this, this was just frightning, my memory could be wrong. Any screen caps ?

Sure, here you go.

It seems like it, the name tells me something, is this movie a remake ? I think I watched the first version because someone told me it was in that movie but didn't find that scene, it would explain a lot.

Yeah, it's one of several adaptations of a 1955 novel. The 1978 one is considered a classic.

Let me guess, the scene I'm talking about is only in the 1993 version ?

I think so, yes. But I've been wrong before ;)

Alright thanks a lot, you could in theory add an anwser to this question so I can close it :) I found myself a nice movie for the approaching week-end

This sounds like a scene from Body Snatchers (1993), one of several adaptations of a 1955 novel.

The teenager Marti Malone is traveling along her summer vacations with her father, the EPA inspector Steve Malone, her stepmother Carol Malone and her young stepbrother Andy to a military base where her father will inspect some toxic products. In a gas station bathroom on the road, she is scared by a soldier that advises her to not sleep, because they get you when you sleep. Once in the base, she becomes friend of Jean Platt, the daughter of the general in charge of the base, and the helicopter pilot Tim Young. Marti and her father see that people are acting strange, and sooner they find that aliens are cloning the human beings in the base and invading Earth.

In one scene, Marti (Gabrielle Anwar) relaxes in a bath when an alien pod in the ceiling slowly extends its tentacles at her and tries to replicate her. She survives this attempt. The aftermath is briefly seen around the minute mark in the trailer:




I confirm, I found the Not So Safe For Work scene on youtube, no wonder I had bad dreams, they don't hijack their body, THEY CLONED IT !!! Will watch this this week-end, and come to think about it, the version I was told to watch was with Mr. Sutherland, which I was expecting to have this scene, no wonder I why I didn't find it, it was the "right" movie, just not the right version haha. Thank you x10000
